# Cross UI thread invalid operation with async await

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, async-await

I'm trying to implement async await into my application and I'm running into some difficulties

in what looks easy yet it's not working out as such.  I have the code below which I would have through awaiting the LoadAsync would perform the WCF service call and return the data, then I could load the Tasks form.  However with the await call I get a cross-ui thread exception on the instancing of the Tasks form.  If I remove await then it works.  What am I doing wrong?

```
if (!Core.Tasks.IsLoaded)
{
await Core.Tasks.LoadAsync();
}
Core.ShowWait("Opening Tasks");
TasksForm frm = new TasksForm() { MdiParent = Core.MainMDIWindow, CurrentViewName = Core.CurrentUser.UserProfile.TasksLastViewName }; // <-- error on this line
```

The LoadAsync method is:

```
public override Task LoadAsync(bool includeDeleted = false)
{
    return Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Core.Logger.EnterMethod("_TasksData.Load");
        try
        {
            DataSet = Core.LogbookProData.Tasks.GetTasks(DataUserID, includeDeleted);
            LoadCompleted();
            dsTasks cacheData = await Cache.LoadAsync(ConvertTimeZone);
            if (cacheData != null)
                MergeDataSets(DataSet, cacheData);

            InitializeLayouts();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Core.Logger.LogException("_TasksData.Load", ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            Core.Logger.LeaveMethod("_TasksData.Load");
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access any UI objects from a background thread. `Task.Run` executes its delegate on a background thread, so if there's anything in the `Task.Run` delegate that accesses the UI (e.g., `InitializeLayouts` sounds suspect), then you'll get an exception like this.

`Task.Run` should really only be used if you have a CPU-bound operation, or if you only have a blocking API for what *shoud* be an asynchronous call. It's not *normally* used to implement `async` methods. You may find my [`async`/`await` intro post helpful](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

For example, if `GetTasks` and `MergeDataSets` do not block too long, you could implement `LoadAsync` like this:

```
public override async Task LoadAsync(bool includeDeleted = false)
{
    Core.Logger.EnterMethod("_TasksData.Load");
    try
    {
        DataSet = Core.LogbookProData.Tasks.GetTasks(DataUserID, includeDeleted);
        LoadCompleted();
        dsTasks cacheData = await Cache.LoadAsync(ConvertTimeZone);
        if (cacheData != null)
            MergeDataSets(DataSet, cacheData);

        InitializeLayouts();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Core.Logger.LogException("_TasksData.Load", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        Core.Logger.LeaveMethod("_TasksData.Load");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx - I tried removing the Task.Run but that made no difference.  Very hard bug to track down sadly.

Comment: Take a look at the stack trace for the exception. That should give you a good starting point.